# Spring boot jar file, not reading application.properties in config folder

Tags: spring-boot

I have a jar file from a Spring Boot project created with "mvn clean install". I created a folder named "config" and placed the "application.properties" in that folder

However the application is still not using the external application.properties file, but it's using the one inside the jar file. How can I make it use the external application.properties if it exists.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything as Spring Boot will pick up files in `config/` (relative to the current working directory) automatically. Note that external `application.properties` files are used in addition to any found inside your jar (on the classpath) with the former taking precedence over the latter for any properties that are defined in both places.

Comment: That explains it, I should remove it from the original application.properties since it's also defined in there